# Jasperreport parameter selection from SQL query

Tags: jasper-reports, report, data-warehouse, jasperserver, parameterized

I wanted to create a JasperReport which asks the user for a deliverer before it creates a report with data of the last the deliveries of the selected deliverer.

The problem, how I can do that? I found only examples where a parameter is created and the ArrayList is filled statically. But in my parameter I need the query result over the table of deliverers filled.
Can anybody tell me a possible solution?

I'm using Jaspersoft Server 5.1 which directly access a PostgreSQL database which has a datawarehouse structur. So it's not possible to use Java code.

Comment: To be more clear, I have two tables "factum_delivery" with a deliverer id and "dim_deliverer". The report should fill the parameter selection with a list from "SELECT id, name from dim_deliverer".
The user selects one of the deliverer. After that in my second query SELECT * from factum_delivery WHERE deliverer_id = $P{sel_deliverer_id} the data for the table and the chart is extracted.
Researching now over 2 days but havent't found anything like this in the example reports as well as in the documentation or webinars :-(.
Is this so complicated or am I too stupid?

Comment: Are you looking for a query-based input control?

Comment: @Lisa: Yes, at the end there should be a combobox on the left where you can select the deliverer for a dashboard. on the right the report is created for that deliverer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the documentation for adding input controls to reports in JasperReports Server:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-user-guide/adding-input-controls

Scroll down to the section that deals with query-based input controls. Your input control will have a name, such as deliverer. In your report, you must add deliverer as a parameter and reference it in your query, as you have done in your comment.

Comment: Ohh. That's what I've searched for :-). Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can also create cascading input controls, where the available options in one input control are determined by a selection made in a prior input control. Instructions for those are in the same document. Good luck!